# Dynamic DNS updates via DHCP on CentOS

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, dhcp

I'm running mostly Ubuntu VMs in an vSphere cluster where a VLAN is managed by a Windows DHCP and DNS. From the Ubuntu VMs I can update the DNS records in the Windows DNS to point the dynamic IP to its hostname (set in `/etc/hostname`) with `dhcp-identifier: mac` addition in `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`:

```
cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
  version: 2
```

After these modification a call to `dhclient -r` also updates the DNS record to point to the newly dhcp-assigned IP address.

But now I want to achieve the same DNS update functionality in a CentOS 7 VM. First I setted `/etc/hostname` to `myhost.example.tld` and rebooted the machine. After that I tried to change serveral variables in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens192`:

- Setting `MACADDR` to either `preserve` or `permanent`
- Setting `DHCP_HOSTNAME` to `myhost` but not `DHCP_FQDN`
- Setting `DHCP_FQDN` to `myhost.example.tld` but not `DHCP_HOSTNAME`

Every change to ifcfg-ens192 were followed by the invocation of `dhclient -r ens192; dhclient ens192` and a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. One needs to create `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and add `send fqdn.fqdn = gethostname();` to it. After that, a `dhclient -r; dhclient` sends the hostname in the DHCP* message.